# Runtime Create Audio Fail - Refresh from Cache or Server?

Tags: javascript, audio, page-refresh

I am creating Audio at runtime and then setting the source.

```
let snd = new Audio();
snd.src = "file.mp3";
```

It works in Edge every time. Occasionally, it fails in Chrome, especially when I am debugging. It only really fails on the first time I start debugging in a session, almost always working every time after. Once it works, it repeatedly works for that session.

Note the error is `MEDIA_ERR_SRC_NOT_SUPPORTED`, which I know is not true, because it works, typically, the second time.

From what I have read here on Stackoverflow, there may be a known problem with this for large sound files (which this is in my case).

So my solution is, refresh the page when an onerror is fired:

```
snd.onerror = _ => window.location.refresh(true);
```

Note the `true`.

When you do this `true` means you are refreshing from the server. `false` means you are refreshing from the cache.

**QUESTION: Considering my problem, which should I be doing, `true` or `false`?**

Because of the low fail-rate, this is a real pain to debug, so any advice will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is `true`. That worked every time. `false` only worked a few of the times. But as I say, since this is an intermittant error, it is very difficult to debug.